# How do I capture the url-path to do a htaccess redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

What I'm looking to do is take `http://mydomain.com/1a3b5c` and redirect it to `http://mydomain.com/page?id=1a3b5c` and if possible still keep `mydomain.com/1a3b5c` in the browser's address bar. If this isn't possible, then the simple redirect is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are interested in is typically called 'Clean URLs' and is done like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /page?id=$1 [L]
```

This is assuming you are using Apache as your web server and have mod_rewrite enabled.

It will preserve the original visible URI.

This may need to be modified based on your precise needs, but this should give you the general direction of where to go.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this`<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./sort?id=$1`

Comment: Yeah, that is great. That <Files ...> tag isn't doing anything. FollowSymLinks is just good practice to have there, RewriteEngine On is sometimes necessary to make the thing work at all, and their RewriteRule is somewhat more elegant (and loose, but probably in a good way) than mine. I'd use the one you found. The one I posted is in use on my server and works nicely so it's a good rudimentary fallback if you encounter problems.

Answer (score 2):

If your webserver is apache you want to use Mod Rewrite. Something like this I think

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\?
RewriteRule (.*) page=$1
```